# SQL Server varbinary bigint with BitConverter.ToInt64 values are different

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bigint

I save my `long` value in a SQL Server table as `varbinary(max)`:

```
var savedValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(longValue);
```

Now I need to work with that value in T-SQL query, but when I trying to get value:

```
select cast(Value as bigint) from dbo.MyValues
```

It returns different number value. For example if I saved `-8588797048854775808` in .NET, in T-SQL I get `33802181122903688`

Please tell me what's the problem? Have that issue any solution?

Comment: why do you save a 64-bit integer as varbinary in the first place?

Comment: Typically you would store `long` in C# as `bigint` in SQL Server. Is there a particular reason you are trying to store `long` as `varbinary`?

Comment: Because that DB field don't contains only int64 type values.

Comment: You could create a C# assembly and install it using SQL-CLR into SQL Server to handle this conversion back to `Int64` again....

Comment: Your questions is absolutly right but in my case I just refator already existed solution. I want to divide that column for new others by type. And I need to transmit data from old column to new without any lose and actually I can't use .NET applications or CLR Intergating for my aim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Casting from `varbinary` to `bigint` (and back) uses network byte order (big-endian).
`BitConverter` uses the endian-ness of the machine it is run on (little-endian for x86 and x64).

Hence `BitConverter.GetBytes` run on -8588797048854775808 (0x88CE7696E7167800) is {0x00,0x88,0xE9,0x18,0x69,0x89,0x31,0x77}, and `cast` on {0x00,0x88,0xE9,0x18,0x69,0x89,0x31,0x77} is 0x0088E91869893177 = 38536887891734903.

The obvious thing to do is to just store 64-bit integers as 64-bit integers in the first place.

If you really need to do this conversion then:

```
var savedValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(longValue))
```

Will swap around the bytes, while also being portable in that it won't swap the bytes if run on a big-endian machine.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the System.Net namespace for some reason, or if you want to be extensible to types other than the three `IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder` handeles, use:

```
var savedValue = BitConverter.GetBytes(longValue);
if(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
  Array.Reverse(savedValue);
```

Comment: Thank you for your explaination of this issue. But I don't planing to save 'long' values to 'varbinary' again. I just need some tool to get already existing 'bigint' values in that column like I get values within '.NET BitConverter.ToInt64'. I need something like 'Array.Reverse(savedValue);' only within 'TSQL' query environment

Comment: Thanx Jon I found!
In that case I need to use `reverse` function in `TSQL`:

`select cast(cast(reverse(Value) as varbinary(max)) as bigint) from dbo.MyValues`

Comment: Regardless of the asker's DB design, this question helped me solve a similar problem when trying to implement a C# equivalent of a T-SQL HASHBYTES function. I was not even aware of the possibility of the endian order being different. Thanks!