# Write T-SQL functionality in .NET

Tags: c#, t-sql

I have this bit of t-sql code

```
set @UrlHash = convert(bigint, hashbytes('MD5', @Url))
```

I wonder if I can write a function in C# which returns me the exact same hash as the line above without going to SQL.

Is it possible?

Requirement is that C# MUST created exact same hash.

Comment: Curious given that an MD5 hash is 128-bit and a bigint is 64-bit how does this even work?

Comment: There is an MD5 class which implements the MD5 hash algorithm. That sounds like what your looking for.

Comment: Check out System.Security.Cryptography.MD5

Comment: ok. but how about the convert bigint piece? even if I get a byte array from the MD5 hash... how will the convert and bigint piece workout?

Comment: Looks like it might be an endian issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8467072/21727

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The select

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, HASHBYTES('MD5', 'http://stackoverflow.com'))
```

will yield the following result:

```
-3354682182756996262
```

---

If you now try to create a MD5 hash in C#

```
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
byte[] textToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("http://stackoverflow.com");
byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash); 
long numeric = BitConverter.ToInt64(result, 0);
```

`numeric` will be `8957512937738269783`.

---

So what's the issue (besides the fact that a MD5 hash is 128-bit and `BIGINT`/`long` is just 64-bit)?

It's an [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue (the bytes are in the wrong order). Let's fix it using the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) class and reverse the bytes as needed:

```
MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();
byte[] textToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("http://stackoverflow.com");
byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash); 

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(result);

long numeric = BitConverter.ToInt64(result, 0);
```

`numeric` is now `-3354682182756996262` as you want.

Comment: I missed that mbeckish already found a possible duplicate: [SQL Server varbinary bigint with BitConverter.ToInt64 values are different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467072/sql-server-varbinary-bigint-with-bitconverter-toint64-values-are-different)

Answer (score 0):

You should use MD5 class, here is the example from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx, with output as int 64 :

```
public int64 CalculateMD5Hash(string input)
{
    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

    return BitConverter.ToInt64(hash, 0);
}
```

Comment: and what about the covert function? we cannot cast the byte[] into a Int64. can we?

Comment: but the hashes don't match if you pass http://www.google.com to the code about (instead of ASCII I use unicode) it produces -5931442742085820074 whereas t-sql produces -7038863548646352319

select convert(bigint, hashbytes('MD5', N'http://www.google.com')

Comment: Sorry the hashes match till at the level of MD5 creation... but when we convert to bigint ... at that point of time the numbers differ.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't an MD5 hash standard? Can't you use a standard MD5 C# implementation? What about using the code in [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx)?