# SQL bigint hash to match c# int64 hash

Tags: c#, sql-server, hash, bigint, uint64

I am trying to create a universal hashing alogrithim that hashes a string as a 64 bit int.

I am able to hash the strings correctly:
sql:

```
select  
    convert
    (
        varchar(64),
        HASHBYTES
        (
            'SHA1',
            'google.com'
        ),
        2
    )
```

returns `BAEA954B95731C68AE6E45BD1E252EB4560CDC45`

C#

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 c = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] b = c.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("google.com"));
    for (int i = 0; i < b.Length;i++ )
    {
        byte by = b[i];
        sb.Append(by.ToString("x2").ToUpper());
    }

    return sb.ToString();
```

retruns `BAEA954B95731C68AE6E45BD1E252EB4560CDC45`

However when I convert to a bigint/long the values do not match:
sql:

```
select  
    convert
    (
        bigint,
        HASHBYTES
        (
            'SHA1',
            'google.com'
        )
    )
```

returns `2172193747348806725`

c#:

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 c = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
    byte[] b = c.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("google.com"));
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(b, 0);
```

returns `7501998164347841210`

Any ideas on how to get these numbers to match?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467072/sql-server-varbinary-bigint-with-bitconverter-toint64-values-are-different for a possible solution.

Comment: Instead of generating your own hashes on objects you should just use [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx), its much more effective than reinventing the wheel, strings with the same characters will produce the same `"HashCode"`.

Comment: @Killrawr: GetHashCode should only be used to balance a hash table. We have no evidence that the original poster is attempting to balance a hash table; it looks rather like they are attempting a crypto strength hash.  It is very, very important to **never use GetHashCode** for a crypto hash.  It has *none* of the properties that you need to make a secure hash. Again, if you are calling GetHashCode and you are not right now trying to balance a hash table, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert oh I thought I'd recommend it, if the hashes are being used for anything else such as with the `Equals` Method in order to create a efficient `Contract` between objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your SQL bigint takes the last 8 bytes while the c# implementation takes the first 8 bytes (and reverses them because its running on little endian).

Take the proper Range of the array in C# and reverse it. Then you should be fine.

Did some coding:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 c = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();
byte[] b = c.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("google.com"));
long value = BitConverter.ToInt64(b, 12);
value = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(value);

Debug.WriteLine(value);
// writes 2172193747348806725
```

Comment: And you can use `var reversed = BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(longValue))` to swap the bytes.

Comment: @DasKrumelmonster: If you use `BitConverter.GetBytes(IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(longValue))` rather than Linq, it will work regardless of the client's byte order because HostToNetworkOrder() accounts for it.

Comment: Good idea. It operates on a long value though, the endian conversion comes after the bitconverter. Also, I could eliminate linq by utilizing the startIndex parameter.

Comment: if you would rather make sql match
`select  
    convert
    (
        bigint,
  convert
  (
   varbinary(8),
   reverse
   (
    convert
    (
     varbinary(8),
     HASHBYTES
     (
      'SHA1',
      'google.com'
     )
    )
   )
  )
    )`
 
 returns 7501998164347841210

Comment: static long ComputeSha256HashbigInt(string rawData)
        {
            // Create a SHA256   
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
                byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawData));

                if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(bytes);

                long value = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes, 0);

                return value;
            }
        }