# SQL Server Java Compatible GUID / UUID (Big Endian UniqueIdentifier)

Tags: java, .net, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, endianness

I am trying to convert a 128 bit binary to a uniqueidentifier in sql that is the same as in .net and java.

I know java uses big endians, so I would like to make that the base.

I can get the correct endianess in .net, but am really struggling with it in SQL Server.

Java:

```
        byte[] bytesOfMessage = "google.com".getBytes("UTF-8");

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] md5 = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(md5);
        LongBuffer ig = bb.asLongBuffer();
        return new UUID(ig.get(0), ig.get(1));
```

returns 1d5920f4-b44b-27a8-02bd-77c4f0536f5a

.Net

```
    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 c = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
    byte[] b = c.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("google.com"));
    int z = System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0));
    short y = System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 4));
    short x = System.Net.IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(BitConverter.ToInt16(b, 6));
    Guid g = new Guid(z, y, x, b.Skip(8).ToArray());
    return g;
```

returns 1d5920f4-b44b-27a8-02bd-77c4f0536f5a

SQL

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'google.com' --'goolge.com'

DECLARE @md5 BINARY(16) = HASHBYTES
        (
            'MD5',
            @s
        )

DECLARE @a BINARY(4) = 
        CONVERT
        (
            BINARY(4),
            REVERSE
            (
                CONVERT
                (
                    BINARY(4),
                    LEFT(@md5, 4)
                )
            )
        )

DECLARE @b BINARY(2) = 
        CONVERT
        (
            BINARY(2),
            REVERSE
            (
                CONVERT
                (
                    BINARY(2),
                    RIGHT(@md5, 12)
                )
            )
        )

DECLARE @c BINARY(2) = 
        CONVERT
        (
            BINARY(2),
            REVERSE
            (
                CONVERT
                (
                    BINARY(2),
                    RIGHT(@md5, 10)
                )
            )
        )

DECLARE @d BINARY(8) = 
        CONVERT
        (
            BINARY(8),
            RIGHT(@md5, 8)
        )

SELECT  
    CONVERT
    (
        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        @a + @b + @c + @d
    )
```

returns D86B5A7F-7A25-4895-A6D0-63BA3A706627

I am able to get all three to produce the same value when converting to an int64, but the GUID is baffling me.

[Original Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579946/sql-bigint-hash-to-match-c-sharp-int64-hash)

[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467072/sql-server-varbinary-bigint-with-bitconverter-toint64-values-are-different)

Comment: Did you look into writing a .Net CLR function in SQL Server?

Comment: Not to be picky, but why does your SQL show: `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'goolge.com'` instead of `DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'google.com'`?

Comment: One more question: are you sure that using the VARCHAR datatype encodes the string to the same bytes as the UTF-8 encoding you are using in Java and .NET?  Perhaps you can first check intermediate result that the starting string bytes are the same for .NET and sql server (before you create MD5 hash).

Comment: Good catch Sam.  I checked everything, except the obvious.  All three examples now return the same thing.  Hash away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correct the spelling of `google` in your SQL example (it's `goolge` in your post), you get the right result.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support UTF-8 encoding.  See [Description of storing UTF-8 data in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580). Use suggestion from Michael Harmon to add your .NET function to SQLServer to do the conversion.  See [How to encode...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038303/how-to-encode-language-specific-chars-while-converting-varbinary-to-varcharma) for instructions on how to add your .NET function to SQLServer.

Alternatively, don't specify UTF-8 in your Java and .NET code. I believe SQL Server will use same 256 bit encoding for varchar as does Java and .NET. (But not totally sure of this.)

Comment: UTF-8 is the default for my instance of SQL Server.  If your instance is different you would need to amend the java/.net code accordingly.